# Ansible - putting facts in SQLite via Callback

Tags: python, sqlite, callback, ansible, ansible-facts

Working with Ansible 2.0.2.0. Trying to put two facts into a sqlite database.
To achieve it, i'm working with a callback plugin. This is the python script so far;

```
import os
import time
import sqlite3
import json

from ansible.plugins.callback import CallbackBase

dbname = '/etc/ansible/test.db'
TIME_FORMAT='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'

try:
    con = sqlite3.connect(test1)
    cur = con.cursor()
except:
    pass

def log(host, data):

    if type(data) == dict:
        invocation = data.pop('invocation', None)
        if invocation.get('module_name', None) != 'setup':
            return

    facts = data.get('ansible_facts', None)

    now = time.strftime(TIME_FORMAT, time.localtime())

    try:
        # `host` is a unique index
        cur.execute("REPLACE INTO test2 (now, host, serial) VALUES(?,?,?);",
        (
            now,
            facts.get('ansible_hostname', None),
            facts.get('ansible_product_serial', None)
        ))
        con.commit()
    except:
        pass

class CallbackModule(CallbackBase):
    def runner_on_ok(self, host, res):
    log (res, host)
```

This plugin returns all ansible facts in JSON format. 
But I only need a small line of code to input the facts into a sqlite database.

The original source, but only works with ansible 1.x http://jpmens.net/2012/09/11/watching-ansible-at-work-callbacks/

The output gives no error, but nothing is written in the test1.db.

Comment: Original code from provided link use `log` function instead of your 'print` inside `runner_on_ok` method. `log` function actually writes data to sqlite.

Comment: Edited the original post, log(res, host)
Doesn't add data into the database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Working code. Remove `CREATE TABLE` if not needed.

```
from ansible.plugins.callback import CallbackBase
import os
import time
import sqlite3

dbname = './test.db'
TIME_FORMAT='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'

try:
    con = sqlite3.connect(dbname)
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute('CREATE TABLE `test` (`now` TEXT, `host` TEXT UNIQUE)')
    con.commit()
except:
    pass

def log(host, data):

    if type(data) == dict:
        invocation = data.pop('invocation', None)
        if invocation.get('module_name', None) != 'setup':
            return

    facts = data.get('ansible_facts', None)

    now = time.strftime(TIME_FORMAT, time.localtime())

    try:
        # `host` is a unique index
        cur.execute("REPLACE INTO test (now, host) VALUES(?,?);",
        (
            now,
            facts.get('ansible_hostname', None)
        ))
        con.commit()
    except:
        pass

class CallbackModule(CallbackBase):
    def runner_on_ok(self, host, res):
        log(host, res)
```

Comment: Please note that the `result.get('ansible_facts', None)` trick doesn't work on Ansible 2.2 anymore.